# Deprecation warning for using (*args) with method

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm going to be deprecating passing arguments on a method. I know how to use `ActiveSupport::Deprecation` for a method, but the method isn't going anywhere. Just passing arguments to it is going away.

This particular method is used a TON in testing, so I definitely don't want a warning every time! I've already removed the arguments from the tests, so I shouldn't see any warnings when I run the test suite unless someone adds the method with the arguments. How can I make this happen?

Here's a faked version of the method with the `(*args)` that will be deprecated:

```
def assert_in_tests(*args)
  code_happens_here
end
```

The method (once the `(*args)` are deprecated) will be the following (and I don't want a deprecation warning when it's utilized):

```
def assert_in_tests
  code_happens_here
end
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you want a warning every time a method is called in a way that will be deprecated? That seems like exactly what you'd want to make sure the old usage disappears...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the method isn't going anywhere. Just passing arguments to it is going away ... so I shouldn't see any warnings when I run the test suite unless someone adds the method with the arguments

A simple if statement should suffice would it not?

```
def assert_in_tests(*args)
  ActiveSupport::Deprecation.warn("args to be deprecated ...") if args.present?
  code_happens_here
end
```

Comment: Sometimes, it's the simple things that elude a person. :-) Thanks, Miles!